# How to create a pagination system with Mysql and JSP?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, pagination

I created a simple eCommerce application in JSP. I have a database of products stored using Mysql. Everything is well set in the browser except one thing: I'd like to limit the rows per page and allow the user to choose the number of products he can display as well as navigating through the pages.

So far all the tutorials I have come across are in php... which is a very different language from JSP, as you may already know.

Any heads up on how to go about doing this will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of tutorials on this readily available on google.

http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jsp/pagination-in-servlet-and-jsp/

Your question is too broad to be answered here.